# Ruby Page object Gem - Unable to pick a platform for the provided browser (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby

I get this error on running my feature file.

Unable to pick a platform for the provided browser (RuntimeError)

Help required, please.

Here is the code;

```
class GooglePage
  include PageObject

  def self.visitor
    visit("http://www.google.com")
  end

end
```

**env.rb**

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object'
require 'rubygems'
require 'page-object/page_factory'

World (PageObject::PageFactory)
@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox


Step-Definitions

require_relative 'GooglePage'

Given(/^I am on the Google home page$/) do  
   visit(GooglePage)
  # visit('http://www.google.com')

   on(GooglePage).visitor
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
visit(GooglePage)
```

because you haven't called page_url in GooglePage (ln 4 below)

```
class GooglePage
  include PageObject

  page_url "http://www.google.com"    

  def self.visitor
    visit("http://www.google.com")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line **@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox** to the **Before** method in **hooks.rb**

```
Before do
  @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
end

After do
  @browser.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you make your rake file pass on tags and BROWSER and URL,e.g.
`rake my_task BROWSER=chrome URL=http://google.com.au`

and hooks will check if the BROWSER is chrome, then will use the specific Webdriver for chrome. But how to pass the URL in the PageObject?

Currently from hooks I have the ff:

```
when "chrome" then
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
    caps.version = "40.0.2214.115 m"
    caps.native_events = false
    caps.javascript_enabled= true

    # This is for increasing the default timeout to 180
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = 180

    browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    browser.manage.window.maximize 


end

Before do
browser.cookies.clear
@browser = browser
end

After do
unless ENV["BROWSER"].eql? "ie"
    browser.close
    sleep 2
end
end
```

Then on my HomePage pageobject I have the ff:

```
class HomePage
include PageObject

page_url("#{ENV['URL']}")

#opens the url defined in ENV['URL']
def goto_homepage
    visit(HomePage)
end

end
```

Using Watir, the URL got opened, so trying this out in Selenium and it won't work.